# how to convert string into array in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am fetching records from mysql database through while loop.

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM animate ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10") or die("query Field");

 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

$row['code'];

 }
```

output is xyacefg.

Now I want to break this output into an array I want to place each letter into separate index of array like

array('x','y','a','c','e','f','g');

I have used explode

$array = explode(' ', $row['code']);

but it didnot work. now the final code is .

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM animate ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10") or die("query Field");

 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

$row['code'];

 }

$array = explode(' ', $row['code']);
```

Comment: Have you echoed it out? echo var_dump($row['code']);

Comment: Read about using [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) in PHP.

Comment: `$array[] = str_split($row['code'])` inside the loop, `print_r($array)` outside the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to create an empty array and assign value to them like below:-**

```
$new_array = array(); // create a new array
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM animate ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10") or die("query Field");

 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

    $new_array[] = $row['code']; // assign value to array

 }
echo "<pre/>";print_r($new_array); // print array which is created
```

**Note:- My assumption is `$row['code']` giving you value one-by-one because it is in while loop.**

Comment: Nope, _this_ seems to be the correct answer, rather than the (current) top. @Anant

Answer (score 2):

Its easy with [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php):

```
<?php
$array = str_split("xyacefg"); //In your case: str_split($row['code']);
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => x
    [1] => y
    [2] => a
    [3] => c
    [4] => e
    [5] => f
    [6] => g
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use **str_split()** function.
If you want to get exact same result as you want like:

```
array('x','y','a','c','e','f','g');
```

then use following code:

```
<?php
  $string = "xyacefg";
  $exploded = str_split($string);
  echo 'array("'.implode('", "', $exploded).'");';
?>
```